# UIScrollView not Scrolling entirely to see all subviews

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have UIScrollView which contains 4 Views. But when I run the app, I cannot scroll entirely and see the blue view.How can I fix it. I even added `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
         scrollView.addSubview(contentView)
         scrollView.contentSize = contentView.frame.size
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Constraint, check have you given proper height to your contentView, if not then you need to give height to your content view.

In your case contentview height should be sum of all subview it has, i.e pinview's height + yellowview's height + other views height

[image]